# Topdown maps of Moonview Highway?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

Is it possible to get a topdown map of Moonview Highway? (or any track?)

Are they available somewhere? Or with the hacks around, is it possible to pan the view to the sky to look at the track and record it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Moonview Highway map:

http://www.supercheats.com/guides/mario-kart-wii/moonview-highway

All Mario Kari Wii maps:

http://www.supercheats.com/guides/mario-kart-wii/courses/

Not sure about getting a view from a hack though. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! In my opinion, it's easier for the person asking the question if you link to the relevant article on Moonview Highway rather than a general index. Also, it's better for your answer in general to expand a bit on the content of the article or link the image the user was asking for in case the site you've linked to goes down.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I updated my answer, hopefully it's more to the point and helpful. As for expanding the content, all that is included is a list detailing the strategy for numbered points on the map, and wasn't sure if I would be plagairizing if I just copied the list straight out.